# How to calculate autocorrelation in r (zoo object)

Tags: r

I am trying to check for auto-correlation in a zoo object (monthly data with several columns) using:

`acf(jan, plot=F)$acf[2]`

but I get the following error:

`Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : missing values in object`

To simplify, I extracted just one of the columns which I called "a" (so now I have a simple zoo object with index and data), and used:

`acf(a)`

but still get the same error. Can't acf be used in zoo objects?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use

```
acf(coredata(jan))
```

That should work fine. Keep in mind that you have to provide a regularly spaced time series for that to give you a meaningful answer.

Comment: thanks!  It now works if I do it just for one column but not for the matrix, it gives me an error: `> acf(coredata(feb))
Error in acf(coredata(feb)) : 'lag.max' must be at least 0`

Comment: I don't think you can use acf on multivariate series. What do you want to obtain the acf of each column? Or are you interested in the cross correlation between the columns (that would be the ccf not the acf)?

Answer (score 4):

The default behaviour for `acf` is `na.action = na.fail`. Try setting it to `na.omit` or `na.pass` in your call `acf(..., na.action = na.omit)`

Comment: @sbg, `acf` works on regularly spaced data so `acf` first expands the  time series to a regularly spaced one inserting NAs as needed to make it regularly spaced.

Comment: @Grothendieck, thanks but it is monthly data so it is regularly spaced

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you when trying to use the ACF function on monthly S&P returns.
Turns out the coredata function solved the problem as it stripped date information from returns in my data set from yahoo finance.

you might want to give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

Or self made

```
autocorrplot <- function(x)
{
  n <- length(x)
  barplot(sapply(1:10,function(i) cor(x[-i:-1],x[(-n-1+i):-n])))
}
```